# loadHTTPProvider error on wowza

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming, wowza

I am in process of developing a Wowza service for broadcasting on am Amazon + wowza+ cloudfront setup with a bit of extra logic .
The application runs smooth when tested on local machine via Eclipse IDE . However the same settings on amazon shows loadHTTPProvider error .

I have tried changing the permission and owner to same as other for my application components inside conf and applications folders however all in vain as it doesnot show me required output . **However the basic functionality of publishing and viewing a stream works fine so that proves that application is loaded but not all the components** .

Here is the error trace . Any help on suggesting what might be missing here are most welcomed .

[image]
( I had posted this question on [Wowza forum](https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/6822/loadhttpprovider-error.html) approx 24 hours back , no response there so far , hence posting here )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first confirm that you've placed the custom http provider jar file in your production environment (lib folder) along with any other jar files that it may reference.  Then restart Wowza and try again.

If you should experience any further trouble, valid license holders can send support requests to support[at]wowza.com.  If you do this, please ensure you include a zip file of your production conf/ and lib/ folders for further review.

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: Request you to help me resolve my issue pertaining to signedcookies in Cloudfront for livestream . I have posted it in wowza forum here - http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?43436-Signed-Cookie-for-Cloudfront-Wowza-HTTP-live-streaming&p=154478#post154478

Comment: It should be noted that the link in the above comment by @Altanai has been moved to https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/6823/signed-cookie-for-cloudfront-wowza-http-live-strea.html